# Azure Functions With Managed Identity Access Azure SQL Specific Schema

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

My scenario is following

- Azure Functions ( There are multiple function apps) with Managed Identity available.
- Each Function App has access to specific schema in Azure SQL. This is Single Database with Multiple schema scenario.

As per microsoft document I have to do following to allow function app access to DB.

```
CREATE USER [<identity-name>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
GO
```

This works fine but issue is that it can access entire database. I want to allow each function app to access only single schema within a database. Specially it creates issue when EF core migration is being executed. How can we give specific function app to completely manage specific schema of database.

Comment: something like that should work: `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA :: <schema> TO <user>;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `db_datareader`, `db_datawriter`, etc. role assignment, you can use `GRANT` permission statement.

Refer the below example:

`GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::HumanResources TO role_HumanResourcesDept;`

where `HumanResources` is a schema and `role_HumanResourcesDept` is the user.

Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15